# Need help reading information line by line and from a txt file using it in code.

Tags: c, line, fgets, scanf

I've been asked to create a text file with lines containing the following format. Each type of information(or field) has to be separated by a space and each line has to end with a newline character:

```
Category1 LabelA 0.32 10 0.60  8
Category1 LabelX 0.24 12 0.90  4
Category2 LabelZ 0.55 14 1.50  10
```

I've been asked to read through it and using functions with pointers to make calculations with the integers for each category as well as total calculations for all categories. I have two questions.

- Should i end each line in the txt file with \n or will simply hitting
  enter(as one would normally type it) suffice?
- How should I read from
  the file and store values without modifying or opening it? I'm
  confused as to use fgets or fscanf.

Comment: Just hit enter, and open the file in text mode and everything will be okay with regards to line endings.

Answer (score 0):

logic:

- loop while `!feof(FILE)`

  1. `fgets()` 1 line
  2. `sscanf()` the line
  3. do your calculation!

The following code can be optimized to reduce calls to functions, but for clarity of expression, I've created multiple functions.. each that do 1 job only:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_data(const char *ptr, char *category, char *label, float *f1,
          int *fint, float *f2, int *sint) //fint = first-int, sint is second int
{
  sscanf(ptr,"%s%s%f%d%f%d\n", category, label, f1, fint, f2, sint); 
}

const char *get_line(FILE *f, char *target, size_t size)
{
  fgets(target, size, f);
}

double random_calculation(float f1, int fint, float f2, int sint) 
{
  return f1 * fint + f2 * sint;
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buffer[512];
  char label[50], category[50];
  FILE *file;
  float f1, f2; 
  int fint,sint;
  double answer;
  if(argc != 2) { puts("No file!"); return 0;}
  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");//open in text mode
  if(!file) return;
  while(!feof(file)) {
    get_line(file, buffer, 511);
    puts(buffer);
    get_data(buffer, category, label,&f1,&fint, &f2, &sint);
    answer = random_calculation(f1, fint, f2, sint);
    printf(">>> %s %s: %lf\n\n", category, label, answer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would i store data from two lines with the same category? Would i just do the following?:

get_data(buffer, category,label,&f1,&fint, &f2, &sint);

get_data(buffer, category2,label2,&f3,&fint2,&f4,&sint2);

if (category==category2)

{answer = rand_calc(f1,f3,....etc}

Comment: data from the same category? You need a hashtable that maps `category` to your `data` structure

Comment: could i not store it in some sort of int/float array such as categoryA sint[]? I haven't learnt anything with hashtables yet.

Comment: sure you can, do that as well! @user2014885